# Find min max from two different tables

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I have 3 tables in a MYSQL DB

ORDER

```
   order_id | order_date
-------------------------
      1     | 2021-09-20    
      2     | 2021-09-21
```

PRODUCTS

```
   product_id | product_price
------------------------------
      1       | 30    
      2       | 34
      3       | 39
      4       | 25
```

ORDER_PRODUCTS

```
   product_id | order_id | discount_price
------------------------------------------
      1       | 1        |   null
      2       | 1        |   18
      1       | 2        |   null
      4       | 2        |   null
```

Now I want to know the min and max prices of all products in a specific ORDER record when I give a specific product_id (I need all the ORDERS that have the provided product) group by order_id. I got the required data for this, but here is the tricky part, the `ORDER_PRODUCTS` table will have the discounted_price for that particular product for that specific ORDER.

So, when computing MIN, MAX values I want `discount_price` to be prioritized instead of `product_price` if that product doesn't have any `discount_price` then `product_price` should be returned.

EX:

```
order_id  | min_price                     | max_price
------------------------------------------------------
      1   | 18(p_id=2)(discount price)    | 30(p_id=1)
      2   | 25(p_id=4)                    | 30(p_id=1)
```

Comment: `p_id=2` has discount price = 18 for order_id = 1. Why is max_price = 34?

Comment: @forpas Sorry, max_price should be 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for the `IfNull()`function, you can read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_ifnull.asp)

You can simply surround the `IfNull()`function in the appropriate aggregate function

```
select o.order_id, 
min(ifnull(discount_price,product_price)), 
max(ifnull(discount_price,product_price)) 
from PRODUCTS p  
inner join ORDER_PRODUCTS op on op.product_id  =p.product_id  
inner join ORDER o on o.order_id = op.order_id
group by o.order_id, p.product_id
```